# Tips to find area between curves without do the graph first

Tags: calculus

Is there any quick or detail way to find area between two/three/multiple curves without do the graph first? I mean to know which curve is the upper and lower or righter and lefter.

[Here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/AreaBetweenCurves.aspx) is the problems example for quick reference.

Comment: Find the intersections. Checking points left, right, above, below and conclude where the curves are.

Comment: Or more easily, find the intersections, which parcel out main interval into subintervals. Then regardless of which is on top find integrals of difference over each subinterval, but make them all positive before adding them all up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you find the points of intersection don't worry about finding which is on top or bottom and just calculate the absolute value of each integral. E.g. If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have intersections at $x_0$, $x_1$, $x_2$, etc. then find:

$$\bigg|\int_{x_0}^{x_1}f(x)-g(x)dx\bigg|+\bigg|\int_{x_1}^{x_2}f(x)-g(x)dx\bigg|+\bigg|\int_{x_2}^{x_3}f(x)-g(x)dx\bigg|+...$$

Comment: Is that too risky to take absolute value? I mean, let's say the final result of a problem would be $1$ if I do $f(x)-g(x)$ and $-3$ if I do $g(x)-f(x)$ and I take the absolute value. So they are different. Or should I try your equation first? (It's my worry after first glance)

Comment: The order of the integration will not change the magnitude of the answer only the sign. Recall that $\int-y dx = -\int y dx$ so $$\int f(x)-g(x) dx = -\int g(x)-f(x) dx$$ and then the absolute value will take care of any negatives that occur.